# Assigning not by-reference variable to a function returning by-reference, and vice-versa

Tags: c++, stack

While this may be a simple question, I was not able to find an answer probably because these situations are not covered in your standard pass-by-value and pass-by-reference tutorials.  I am familiar with both principles, but I cannot pinpoint exactly what the compiler does in the following two scenarios.  I am looking for an explanation as to what happens **on the stack** and **when** the compiler makes any copies of objects versus simply assigning addresses.

Consider the following function:

```
int & foo();
```

What happens when `a` is not by-reference?

```
int a = foo(); // a is not int &
```

Consider the next function:

```
int bar();
```

What happens when `b` is by-reference?

```
int & b = bar(); // bar is not by-reference
```

Comment: It's a misnomer to say that "functions return stuff". That's not what's happening. Function call expressions are evaluated, and the evaluation produces a value. A value is always an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of both expressions `foo()` and `bar()` are values of type `int`. The former is an lvalue, and the latter is an rvalue. When you say `int a = foo();` or `int a = bar()`, the local object variable `a` is initialized with that value. When you say `int & b = foo()`, the local reference variable `b` is bound to the value on the right (which is an lvalue). The statement `int & b = bar()` is invalid because references cannot bind to rvalues.

Comment: I edited the question because there was obviously a typo in the second example (now calling `bar()` instead of `foo()`)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case simply the value is copied from what is currently contained in the object referenced by the reference returned by the function.

The second case is illegal with a non-const reference, in case of a const reference instead the referenced object returned by the function will be kept alive until the reference goes out of scope (there is a very specific rule for this in the C++ language).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the object that the reference is bound to (*i.e.*, the object denoted by the value returned) is copied into `a`. No temporary is introduced to hold the return value.

In the second case, it won't compile, since `bar()` is an rvalue.